# K6 Http_req_duration metric returns 0 on the endpoint

Tags: k6

Please help me, I am loading the server. After the test, the time in http_req_duration is 0 in the metrics for the request to the upi file, and if the load is reduced, the time is shown. I looked at the nginx logs there are no errors, there are status codes 200 and 304, what could this be related to?

```
import http from 'k6/http';
const file = JSON.parse(open('./urls.txt'));


const rate_num = 10
const duration_num = '5s'
const preAllocatedVUs_num = 500
const maxVUs_num = 5000

export const options = {
    scenarios: {
        'loadTesting': {
            executor: 'constant-arrival-rate',
            duration: duration_num,
            rate: rate_num,
            preAllocatedVUs: preAllocatedVUs_num,
            maxVUs: maxVUs_num,
            exec: 'oneTest'
        },
        'loadTesting1': {
            executor: 'constant-arrival-rate',
            duration: duration_num,
            rate: rate_num,
            preAllocatedVUs: preAllocatedVUs_num,
            maxVUs: maxVUs_num,
            exec: 'twoTest'
        },
        'loadTesting2': {
            executor: 'constant-arrival-rate',
            duration: duration_num,
            rate: rate_num,
            preAllocatedVUs: preAllocatedVUs_num,
            maxVUs: maxVUs_num,
            exec: 'threeTest'
        },
        'loadTesting3': {
            executor: 'constant-arrival-rate',
            duration: duration_num,
            rate: rate_num,
            preAllocatedVUs: preAllocatedVUs_num,
            maxVUs: maxVUs_num,
            exec: 'fourTest'
        },
        'loadTesting4': {
            executor: 'constant-arrival-rate',
            duration: duration_num,
            rate: rate_num,
            preAllocatedVUs: preAllocatedVUs_num,
            maxVUs: maxVUs_num,
            exec: 'fiveTest'
        },
    },

    thresholds: {}
}

file.forEach((widgets) => {
    widgets.forEach(url => {
        options.thresholds[`http_req_duration{url_${file.indexOf(widgets)}:${url}}`] = ['p(95) < 10000']
    })
})



// ${file.indexOf(widgets)}
const one = []
file[0].forEach(widgets => one.push(['GET', widgets, null, {tags: {url_0: widgets}}]))

const two = []
file[1].forEach(widgets => two.push(['GET', widgets, null, {tags: {url_1: widgets}}]))

const three = []
file[2].forEach(widgets => three.push(['GET', widgets, null, {tags: {url_2: widgets}}]))

const four = []
file[3].forEach(widgets => four.push(['GET', widgets, null, {tags: {url_3: widgets}}]))

const five = []
file[4].forEach(widgets => five.push(['GET', widgets, null, {tags: {url_4: widgets}}]))

export function oneTest() {
    http.batch(one)
}

export function twoTest() {
    http.batch(two)
}

export function threeTest() {
    http.batch(three)
}

export function fourTest() {
    http.batch(four)
}

export function fiveTest() {
    http.batch(five)
}
```

At the output I get:

1. http_req_duration{url_0:https://url1} = p(90) 2434ms
2. http_req_duration{url_0:https://url.glb} = p(90) 0ms

If you reduce the time and rate, then there will be no zero, but there will be time

```
    { expected response:true } min=4.39 med=26.53s max=30.98s p(90)=30.09s 
✓ { url_0.lb } min=0 s med=0 s max=0 sp(90)=0 s 
✓ { url_1} min=0 s med=0 s max=0 sp(90)=0 s 
✓ { url_2 } min=4.39 med=4.39 max=4.39 p(90)=4.39s 
✗ {url_3} min=26.53s med=28.76s max=30.98s p(90)=30.54s





data_received.............................................................: 472 MB 12 MB/s
     data_sent.................................................................: 1.1 MB 28 kB/s
     http_req_blocked..........................................................: min=33.98ms med=53.61ms max=67.58ms  p(90)=64.79ms 
     http_req_connecting.......................................................: min=15.81ms med=17.78ms max=24.42ms  p(90)=23.09ms 
     http_req_duration.........................................................: min=4.39s   med=26.53s  max=30.98s   p(90)=30.09s  
       { expected_response:true }..............................................: min=4.39s   med=26.53s  max=30.98s   p(90)=30.09s  
     ✓ { url_0:https://example1/a8f62275.glb }....: min=0s      med=0s      max=0s       p(90)=0s      
     ✓ { url_1:https://example2/53297a9a.glb }....: min=0s      med=0s      max=0s       p(90)=0s      
     ✓ { url_2:https://example3/e8670d23.glb }...: min=4.39s   med=4.39s   max=4.39s    p(90)=4.39s   
     ✗ { url_3:https://example4/df0dac9f.glb }....: min=26.53s  med=28.76s  max=30.98s   p(90)=30.54s  
     ✓ { url_4:https://example5/a97ef0d7.glb }....: min=0s      med=0s      max=0s       p(90)=0s      
     http_req_failed...........................................................: 0.00%  ✓ 0        ✗ 3    
     http_req_receiving........................................................: min=4.36s   med=26.51s  max=30.95s   p(90)=30.06s  
     http_req_sending..........................................................: min=62.12µs med=66.02µs max=159.06µs p(90)=140.45µs
     http_req_tls_handshaking..................................................: min=18.09ms med=19.61ms max=27.8ms   p(90)=26.16ms 
     http_req_waiting..........................................................: min=24.36ms med=34.31ms max=34.33ms  p(90)=34.32ms 
     http_reqs.................................................................: 3      0.074741/s
     iteration_duration........................................................: min=4.45s   med=26.6s   max=31.02s   p(90)=30.13s  
     iterations................................................................: 3      0.074741/s
     vus.......................................................................: 500    min=500    max=500
     vus_max...................................................................: 500    min=500    max=500
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? Also, what is the number of `http_reqs` and the line below `{expected_response: true}`?

Comment: What is the value of `http_reqs` (and `http_reqs{expected_response:true}`) in the summary? Perhaps your requests are timing out or you have DDoS protection in place?

Comment: @knittl     "http_reqs": {"count": 2001,"rate": 49.896256594738084}, I don't have {expected_response: true}, there is no DDoS protection

Comment: oh sorry, `{expected_response:true}` should be below `http_req_duration`, see https://k6.io/docs/results-output/end-of-test/ for an example

Comment: @knittl Sorry I made a mistake, I have an "expected answer:true" and there the time is counted from requests for which there is no 0

{ expected response:true } min=4.39 med=26.53s max=30.98s p(90)=30.09s


`✓ { url_0.lb } min=0 s med=0 s max=0 sp(90)=0 s
✓ { url_1} min=0 s med=0 s max=0 sp(90)=0 s
✓ { url_2 } min=4.39 med=4.39 max=4.39 p(90)=4.39s
✗ {url_3} min=26.53s med=28.76s max=30.98s p(90)=30.54s`

Comment: 30s almost looks like the requests are timeouting (maybe in your app, maybe in your load balancer). the `expected_response:true` line contains the metrics for all successful requests. The line above, contains metrics for all requests. Please [edit] your question to include this data instead of posting it in a comment. But it's odd, if you get successful requests (`expected_response:true`), then the complete metrics cannot be 0. Which k6 version are you using?

Comment: @knittl Version k6 v0.42.0, but why if I give the load less, then the exact time is on all requests?

Comment: Wait, that output looks incorrect. Why do the tags not have values? Can you include `count` in your columns to see how many requests were counted? Too high load could mean that requests time out and never complete. If they don't complete, they will not be recorded in the metric

Comment: @knittl I have made changes to the description and I am not very good at k6

Comment: From the output can be inferred that one request completed against `https://example3/e8670d23.glb` and two requests completed against `https://example4/df0dac9f.glb`. Only 3 (!) requests completed in total. 472 MB is a lot of data for 3 requests (150 MB per request!). How long does your test run/what's the full duration of the test run? (Unrelated: why do you have 5 different tag keys instead of a single tag with several values?).

Comment: @knittl Initially, the goal was to get the return time of all files that are needed to load web pages, imagine that url_0 is one page, url_2 is another, and so on. And now, for research, I hang a tag on only one endpoint from each page

Comment: But why not `{page: url_0}`, `{page: url_1}`, `{page: https://example1/a8f62275.glb}` etc.? Nevertheless, there were only 3 completed requests – what is the test duration?

Comment: @knittl 5s - 10s

Comment: Okay. If your test can only run for 5 seconds, but your server takes 30 seconds to process your requests, those will not appear in your metrics. The metrics will only include completed requests. A higher request rate could easily overload/block the server

Comment: @knittl Well, but there is no information in nginx logs that some requests have disappeared. And k6 must also wait for a response from the server

Comment: @knittl And also the load on the server was only about 30%

Comment: Well, the requests don't disappear. They eventually complete, but only after the k6 process has stopped. k6 does not wait indefinitely for all requests to complete. The default graceful stop duration is 30 seconds. So any request which takes longer than 35 seconds (5 s test duration + 30 s grace) will not be recorded in the metrics. As to why your server is not handling these requests in a timely fashion, we'd have to know how the server is implemented. All I can say is: the requests haven't completed, that's why you get `0` for them (because there weren't any requests recorded in the metric)